# Как запихнуть массив из vue.js в input как всплывающая подсказка?

Tags: html, vue.js

```
                  <input list="workerFullname" type="text" class="FIO" placeholder="Фамилия Имя Отчество / табельный номер" >
              <datalist id="workerFullname">
              <option v-for="(fullname,index) in bsaInfo.worker_info" :key="index" value="">
                    {{fullname.worker_fullname}}
                  </option>                      
              </datalist>
```

Не работает список вариантов ввода, если указывать любой текс просто так, то все работает, помогите)
Не так силен в этом.

Comment: Если новичек и хочется красиво и функционально, советую воспользоваться фремворком, например Vuetify или аналогом с готовыми компонентами.

Comment: Да мне бы просто понять как сделать, чтобы работал массив. А так спасибо за совет.